# Tooltip Issue with Nvd3 LinePlusBar Chart

Tags: javascript, ajax, d3.js, nvd3.js

Right now i am able to form the Json data and got the lables alligned perfectly on 3 axes(X,y1,y2). The problem i am facing in this chart is the tooltip. I am getting the x axis labelled correctly from the row grouping of my matrix report. So on hovering my pointer i am getting the date value as 12/31/1969 by default at any point instead of taking the date from wherever the pointer is placed.Is there any workaround for that!

Comment: Please provide an example and/or a screenshot and update your question with it.

Comment: @RenatoUtsch this is how my fiddle looks. http://fiddle.jshell.net/2wsu9spc/

Comment: Please take a screenshot of the problem also.

Comment: @RenatoUtsch http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJzpN.png. Please find the attachment.

Comment: @sravan your fiddle is not working, data is not loading, 404 error coming, instead of ajax call, put some sample data statically.

Comment: @saikiran.vsk  Seems like it is working fine for me can you give a try 1 more time please. http://fiddle.jshell.net/2wsu9spc/

Comment: It is not loading. Try loading from accessing computer and you'll notice that.

Comment: Try using nvd3-1.8.1-alpha instead of 1.7.1 and see if the problem with the date on the tooltip is fixed. 1.7.1 had a lot of bugs with the tooltips.

Comment: Here, try with these nvd3 script and css: http://fiddle.jshell.net/2wsu9spc/1/

Comment: @RenatoUtsch Actually i am using the latest version of Nvd3.js only.when i try referencing the 1.8.1 css my chart is whole lot different,it looks pretty bizarre like this http://i.stack.imgur.com/mPst4.png

Comment: Ah, I actually had this problem last week. What was the cause? I think it was related to how you formatted the data.

Comment: @RenatoUtsch I used to have the previous version of nvd3css instead of latest one. while referencing the old css file i am getting the first picture which i sent where i am facing the tooltip issue as 12/31/1969 ,while using the latest css 1.8.1 the chart looks like the latest image which i posted in my previous comment.this is how my chartdat1a alert looks which i am sending toi chart   http://i.stack.imgur.com/YcXSs.png

Comment: Put this json in somewhere you can access as a raw file. For example, http://gist.github.com has that option. Then, reference it in a jsfiddle to use to build your chart and post it here.

Comment: @RenatoUtsch The problem is if i am pasting the Raw json data in place of chartdat1a chart is coming well and good like the NVD3 LBC chart. But the problem is when i send the data from report to chart. it is doing weird things with the tool tip. Is there a way to change the code for (chart.xaxis,chart.tickformat code) i think the problem is with that,right?

Comment: If you paste the raw json and it works, but when you send the data from the report it doesn't, the problem should probably be with the way you parse the data, shouldn't it?

Comment: @RenatoUtsch so don't you think there is a little bit of tweak i need to do at setting the Xaxis or changing the tool tip code? Because from the way i am parsing the json data.the chart is working fine and coming together in the way i want but the only problem i am facing here is the tool tip. When i hover at a particular point on the chart it keeps on displaying the same date where ever i hover,instead of taking it from the x axis.

Comment: So, as I said, I don't remember, it's been too long since I last used 1.7.1. The tooltips were buggy in this version.

Comment: I think the problem you're facing is actually a bug that I reported and that got fixed in 1.8.1-alpha, where the tooltip doesn't call the .x() function when it should.

Comment: @RenatoUtsch Hello ya but as i said i am referencing the same 1.8.1 latest Js and Css and i see a lot of bubbles on the chart as i sent you hte picture before, which seems buggy and i found out that the tooltip is coming somewhere  not at the pointed position and still it shows 12/31/1969 over there if i refer these 2 latest 1.8.1 files.

Comment: I'll repeat. "Put this json in somewhere you can access as a raw file. For example, gist.github.com has that option. Then, reference it in a jsfiddle to use to build your chart and post it here."

Comment: @RenatoUtsch Atlast i found that it is due to version of nvd3js it is creating that tooltip problem. When i try referencing that 1.7.1 js instead of 1.8.1 it works absolutely fine for me. The fiddle looks like this  http://fiddle.jshell.net/pr5e28qp/ , Seems like for me 1.8.1 is not working in my favour:)